# SFTP stopped working after creating a FTP account

Tags: ftp, sftp, plesk

I have created a FTP account using Plesk which is running fine. But since then my SFTP account stopped working. I am new to the whole administration stuff and I can't figure out how the creation of an FTP account affects SFTP.

Comment: have a look into error log on server, why the account "stopped working". Without any further details, there is no way you can get more help.

Comment: It turned out that my IP got blocked after creating a FTP account. After changing my IP I was able to login using SFTP again.

Comment: please, put it into the answer field bellow so it can be helpful for other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my IP got blocked after creating a FTP account. After changing my IP I was able to login using SFTP again.